# Extracting Sub-National admin boundaries or regions from GRUMPv1 or GPW v4

Tags: raster-conversion, administrative-boundaries, africa

GRUMP and Gridded Population of the World (GPW), v4 provides population and demographic values for sub-national levels. However, I am unable to extract the polygons or boundaries from their datasets. They are a mix of admin3, admin2 and urban area extents so getting the boundaries from within these datasets is essential. More so, for African continent there is'nt any source, to my knowledge, covering entire continent at admin level 3.

How can I extract or get to the source polygons for which GRUMP or GPW data is calculated?